# visibility:hidden + z-index makes button invisible in Firefox

Tags: css, button, firefox, z-index

Check this code

```css
.parent {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.child {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<button class="parent">
      <span class="child">content</span>
 </button>
```

**In Firefox on Mac .child remains invisible**.
In chrome and safari .child is visible.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Honestly I would change the markup. For me it doesn't make sense to hide the parent and have a child visible. Most likely one of the scenarios is a wrong implementation of the spec with nothing you can do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox devs fixed it, bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1732921